# $OM$ and $ON$ lines are perpendicular if and only if the $S$, $N$ and $T$ points are collinear

Tags: geometry

A circle with the center in $O$ is tangent inside two secant circles located inside it. If $S$ and $T$ are the tangent points and $M$ and $N$ are the intersection points of the two circles, with $N$ being closer to the right $ST$ than $M$, prove that the $OM$ and $ON$ lines are perpendicular if and only if the $S$, $N$ and $T$ points are collinear. We have shown that if the points are collinear then we have the perpendicular lines but I do not know each other. How should I start?

Comment: Your description is very confusing.  Which is inside --- the circle with center $O$ or the two intersecting circles?  And what exactly is "$N$ being closer to the right $ST$ than $M$" supposed to mean?

Comment: @user10354138  the  two  intersecting  circle

Comment: @user10354138 Take such  that  N  is  closer